# Google Drive gem (Spreadsheet function) - return row of a cell containing specified text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

have done quite a bit of searching/ reading into the documentation. I'm quite new, so it could easily be that the information was there and I just didn't understand it. (Excuse the non-DRYness of the code below, I'm trying to very logically describe what I'm trying to do.)

I'm building an application (Ruby on Rails) that takes user-input data and saves it into a Google Spreadsheet, like so:

```
def save_data_to_spreadsheet
...
  row = 1 + ws.num_rows       #finds last row to begin adding new data in
  ws[row, 1] = self.id        #inputs id (autogen by controller) into that row, 1st col 
  ws[row, 2] = self.name      #inputs user entered name into that row, 2nd col
  ws[row, 3] = self.email     #inputs user entered name into that row, 3rd col
  ws.save
end
```

However, the application also permits users to update their data. In this case, I'd like to not create a new row in the spreadsheet, but update the existing row using the id (which is constant for a given user). Like so:

```
def update_data_to_spreadsheet
...
  row = get_row(self.id)     #finds row that user's data had been stored in using id
  ws[row, 2] = self.name      #inputs user entered name into that row, 2nd col
  ws[row, 3] = self.email     #inputs user entered name into that row, 3rd col
  ws.save
end
```

The problem is that get_row isn't a working method, I made it up because I couldn't determine if there's a method that exists to find the content and return the row. And while I'm happy to write a method, I still couldn't find the right mix of existing methods that would allow me to get the row (e.g., what existing methods allows me to search for self.id in the first column).

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Google spreadsheet api (gData api) can do that. I assume Google Drive gem is using gdata (AFAIK there are only 2 google spreadsheet apis, Gdata & google-apps-script). Gdata has two styles, ListFeed and CellFeed, both feed styles will do and update. - list feed sounds the best bet, as it is SQL like in style.

Comment: I looked at that documentation, do you mind helping me understand what exactly a feed is? With that in mind, I'll re-read the documentation and see if I can think of something that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, this helped, I used Java, not ruby. There is a good Java example. See the Java/Spreadsheet example here https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples?csw=1 It has a Cell and List directory, see CellDemo.java and ListDemo.java. It demos the different things that the feeds do.